# Interactive prompt in perl

Tags: perl, interactive

What is an easy way to provide a string value to my user and let the user edit it... without him having to retype the whole string if it's not 100% correct.

Answer (score 8):

Though it's difficult to tell for sure what you're asking for, you probably want [Term::ReadLine.](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ReadLine.html)

Comment: And if you have GNU Readline available, don't forget to install Term::ReadLine::Gnu (then Term::ReadLine will use it instead).

Comment: If you use Term::ReadLine::Gnu and you distribute your program, you need to distribute your program under the terms of the GPL.

Comment: Nonsense. One required to do so when distributing libreadline, but hardly anyone does that. Instead people merely point to Term::ReadLine::Gnu (which is under the usual dual licence) in their distribution meta file, thus may pick something something different.

Answer (score 4):

See [Term::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::Prompt) or [Prompt::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Prompt::ReadKey).

Answer (score 3):

Or for something a bit higher level, perhaps IO::Prompt

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have Perl 5.10.0 or higher, try Damian Conway's [IO::Prompter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO%3a%3aPrompter) (the successor to IO::Prompt). I wish I could use it for its timeout feature, but alas I'm stuck on Perl 5.8.8.