# Windows Perl line editor with editable default value?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, stdout, stdin

I'm running Strawberry Perl on Windows and I want to print a "Default Value" into the command prompt, so that a user can edit it, then press Enter and Perl will see it as a new STDIN line. I've been told to use [IO::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aPrompt), but it has been established that this does not work in Windows.

Short of making a GUI with [Tk](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk) or something, how can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374147/interactive-prompt-in-perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils::MakeMaker) has a `prompt` function, which is very platform independent.  I'm not suggesting that it be used in your case, but the POD for [IO::Prompt::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Prompt::Tiny) states that its `prompt` function is based on the way `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` does it.  The [smoke tests](http://static.cpantesters.org/distro/I/IO-Prompt-Tiny.html) seem to reflect that IO::Prompt::Tiny has achieved better portability (including Windows).  You might give it a try.

It's a little early in the smoke testing of this new module to say for certain, but if it's based on `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`'s `prompt`, it's designed for portability.

[Term::Prompt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Prompt) is another option.  It has been around longer and has a longer history of multi-platform smoke test success.  But it has non-core dependencies of `Term::ReadKey` and `Text::Wrap`.  `IO::Prompt::Tiny` sticks to core dependencies, if that's a concern.

```
use IO::Prompt::Tiny qw( prompt );
my $input = prompt( 'Proceed? (y/n)', 'n' );
```

Output:

```
Proceed? (y/n) [n]
```

Comment: [IO::Prompter](http://p3rl.org/IO::Prompter) ([test matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=IO-Prompter)) also fares better than IO::Prompt.

Comment: @Sho Minamimoto: I just wanted to follow up a few days later to find out if my answer was helpful and useful to you.

Comment: For this particular case, I actually needed something like Term::ReadLine, but I could not get it to work on Windows, so I just found another workaround. But, yours is helpful in making a default value, I just wanted to also have my user edit it if needed.